# Angular button click with subscriber clean up

Tags: angular, subscriber

If I have a button in the view that calls a function in the controller that gets data via a subscriber from an API service that is an observable, when the observable completes does it clean up the subscriber in the controller or will I have a stack of subscribers for each button click?

View

```
<button (click)="getData">Get Data</button>
```

Controller

```
public getData() {
   this.apiService.getTableData()
      .subscribe(data => {
         this.tableRows = data
      })
}
```

API Service

```
public getTableData(): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(
            observer => {
                this.api.get().subscribe(
                    response => {
                        observer.next(response);
                        observer.complete();
                    },
                    error => {
                        observer.error(error);
                        observer.complete();
                    }
                );
            }
        );
}
```

This is stub code, I'm actually passing variables to the API service from the controller and view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using pipe()? Either with take(1) or takeUntil as param.

Comment: Like @MikkelDalby said in the preceding comment. Plus you can trim `getTableData()` - it can simply `return this.api.get();` (an observable). And the consumer can subscribe with eg `take(1)`